# Python filter URL from plaintext and print filtered result

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, filter

Hi just as the question mention, i would like to ask question how to solve this kind of problem? I use the `if in` method to compare result between line and variable but not all of them matches as some URL have different path. Here are the example of my code

```
urls = ["https://www.facebook.com/SomeCompany", "https://example.com/news/", "https://twitter/test"]
urls = list(dict.fromkeys(urls))
listfile = open("list.txt", 'r')
filtered = []

for url in list(set(urls)):
    for line in listfile:
        if url in line :
            urls.remove(url)
        else:
            filtered.append(url)
    print(' - '.format(filtered))
```

Inside the list.txt plaintext contain only 1 line to filter and that is

```
https://www.facebook.com/
```

What method should be logical to use for me to filter out unwanted URL or its domain name?

Comment: Iterate through them and use string.contains() to check if its in the line. Also, I don't think you need to convert to a list on that one line.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you need to parse the whole url or do you want to extract the hostname from it?

Comment: @NameKhan72 it's either way, i might add domain url without trailing path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

You can use `any()` to check if line is present in list.

```
urls = ["https://www.facebook.com/SomeCompany", "https://example.com/news/", "https://twitter/test"]
var = "https://www.facebook.com/"
if any (var in u for u in urls):
    print(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the hostname from your url, you can do this with urllib:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
parsed_uri = urlparse('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/xy' )
result = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
print(result)

# outputs
'http://stackoverflow.com/'
```